# New/Edit click should redirect to custom form instead of newform.aspx and editform.aspx

Tags: 2010, form

i want to redirect to my custom form when i click on new button in sharepoint list and document libraries.Also , i want same behavior on edit click button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SharePoint Designer open the list and select your custom form. Click the set as default option as shown in the image. You will need to do this for each of the custom form types.

[image]